# "Address already in use" Error while using LinkedIn API

Tags: python, sockets, linkedin-api

I was trying to use Linkedin API to scrape information about companies but i had a socket error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/anhvangiang/Desktop/PY/test.py", line 10, in <module>
application = server.quick_api(key, secret)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/linkedin/server.py", line 25, in quick_api
_wait_for_user_to_enter_browser(app)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/linkedin/server.py", line 39, in _wait_for_user_to_enter_browser
httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(server_address, MyHandler)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 417, in __init__
self.server_bind()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 108, in server_bind
SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 431, in server_bind
self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 48] Address already in use
```

My code is:

```
from linkedin import server
from socket import *

sock = socket()
sock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

key = "key"
secret = "secret"

application = server.quick_api(key, secret)
```

Any suggestions how can i fix the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You could find and kill the process using the:

```
ps aux | grep python
```

Get the process id and kill using:

```
kill -9 PID
```

It will free the address.

OR you can try :

```
application = server.quick_api(key, secret, 5557)
```

Comment: It shows me: 1702   0.0  0.0  2432804   1840 s000  S+    3:44PM   0:00.00 grep python. When i try to use kill -9 on 1702, 2432804, 1840 it all say no such process.

Comment: Is there a space between 2432 and 804?

Comment: There is no space between them.

Comment: can you please try `ps ax | grep python`

Comment: I did and it appears:  1753 s000  S+     0:00.01 grep python then i tried kill -9 1753 but it still say no such process

Comment: Can you run your program and see if it is the error still exist?

Comment: `netstat -anp |grep 8000` execute the command find the process using the port 8000. and kill that process

Comment: Error still exist?

Comment: It requires an argument

Comment: When i type in the command, it asks me for more information regarding an argument

Comment: Can you please give the error? and have you tried the updated `server.quick_api(key, secret, 5557)`

Comment: quick_api only takes 2 arguments and the problem with netstat is: netstat: option requires an argument -- p
Usage: netstat [-AaLlnW] [-f address_family | -p protocol]
 netstat [-gilns] [-f address_family]
 netstat -i | -I interface [-w wait] [-abdgRtS]
 netstat -s [-s] [-f address_family | -p protocol] [-w wait]
 netstat -i | -I interface -s [-f address_family | -p protocol]
 netstat -m [-m]
 netstat -r [-Aaln] [-f address_family]
 netstat -rs [-s]

Comment: https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin/blob/master/linkedin/server.py it show that `quick_api` use a default argument port as 8000. If you can find the process that is using the port and kill it then mostly the above error will be solved is my guess. `netstat` command can be used to find the process using the port. My second guess is to change the default argument 8000 to 5557 and check.

Comment: after giving 3rd argument for `quick_api` what is the error.

Comment: The quick_api only takes 2 arguments

Comment: if you are giving the 3rd argument is it giving error  According to this it can take 3 arguments `quick_api(api_key, secret_key, port=8000)`

Comment: Well if i put in another argument it will certainly give error

Comment: can you please try

Comment: I did earlier when u tell me to put in server.quick_api(key, secret, 5557) and it returns an error

Comment: quick_api only takes 2 arguments, 3 given